# linewidth and middlelinewidth options in mdframed: wrong information in the documentation?

Tags: mdframed, documentation

In the [documentation](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) of the package `mdframed 1.9b`, the author says (p. 7)

> If you are working width framemethod=tikz or framemethod=pstricks the
>   option linewidth is an alias for the option middlelinewidth.

But the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=2mm,
                 linecolor=red]
With \verb+linewidth=2mm+
\end{mdframed}

\bigskip

\begin{mdframed}[middlelinewidth=2mm,
                 linecolor=red]
With \verb+middlelinewidth=2mm+
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Am I missing something or is the documentation wrong on this point?

Comment: is there any possibility that the actual version of `mdframed` you are using is *not* 1.9b?  this statement wasn't in earlier versions of the documentation, although it's not clear when it was added.

Comment: With `mdframed 2013/07/01 1.9b` I get two equal objects (like in your second frame). I get the different behavior if TeX Live 2012 is used (`mdframed 2013/03/09 1.8`)

Comment: @barbarabeeton You might be right! It's 1.8! Thanks!

Comment: @barbarabeeton You can turn your comment to an answer if you want. That was exactly the cause of my problem. Thanxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there any possibility that the actual version of `mdframed` you are using is not 1.9b?

this statement wasn't in earlier versions of the documentation, although it's not clear when it was added.